# Searching for a particular value in listbox in asp.net web form

Tags: c#

I have a listbox in asp.net web form application and i want to search some particular value in the listbox and on clicking the search button,i want the listbox to show only the searched value.How can i do it using C# ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5et1818%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes i tried using dictionary to add values to the list and then copying values from one dictionary to other based on the condition,and thn binding the second dictionary in the listbox.But i m not able to implement this

Comment: @Kiran Bhagat this link is for Windows form.I want to implement this in web form

Answer (score 0):

`lstBox.Items.FindByValue("value").Selected = true;`